# avoiding UNION in sql with counts and different group by

Tags: sql-server, group-by, union

I've put up a simple example of what I'm trying to accomplish and I want to avoid using UNION because:

1 - I would need 9 of them
 2 - It would make my query slow
 3 - Maintenance would be harder and it will be easier to forget to change one of the 9 selects.

```
create table #temp (SA varchar(12), Area varchar(12), Style int)
insert into #temp values ('GA1','GA',2),('GA1','GA',5),('GA2','GA',6),
('GA2','GA',7),('CA1','CA',3),('CA2','CA',2)

select  area, sa, avg (style) Average, count(*) Number from #temp
group by  area, sa
Union
select  area, NULL as sa, avg (style) Average, count(*) Number from #temp
group by area
```

The goal of this query is to have it in a view, so no dynamic code allowed!

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So, `GROUP BY area, sa WITH ROLLUP`?

Comment: yes, looks like its that simple, I was unaware this function existed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ROLLUP` you can get the result. `ROLLUP` generates a result set that shows aggregates for a hierarchy of values in the selected columns. Try this..

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT area,
               sa,
               Avg (style) Average,
               Count(*)    Number
        FROM   #temp
        GROUP  BY rollup ( area, sa )) a
WHERE  area IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, I had no chance with my conventionnal searches, thank you for your quick answer!